How to reference a macro in a ppam via OnAction when modifying the context menu?
I have a ppam that contains a number of usability macros. The macros are all accessed via a customUI Ribbon, but unfortunately due to IT restrictions, not all users can have customised Ribbon UIs. Therefore, I want to add the macros to the context menu as this remains open for modifying.
The problem I have is that I cannot find a way to be able to refer back to a macro within a .ppam file, since there is no 'ThisPresentation' object (compare to ThisWorkbook in Excel, for example). Specifically:
Public Sub changeContextMenu()

    Dim subMenu As CommandBarControl
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim namesOfMenus() As Variant
    Dim menuPopUps As CommandBarPopup, splitMenu As CommandBarPopup
    namesOfMenus = Array("Thumbnails", "Slide Gap")
    
    For i = LBound(namesOfMenus) To UBound(namesOfMenus)
        With Application.CommandBars(namesOfMenus(i)).Controls.Add
            .Caption = "&Insert Slides From File"
            .BeginGroup = True
            .OnAction = "modRibbonInterface.cllbckInsertSlides" 
        End With
    Next i
End Sub

Under .OnAction =, I have no way to point the macro to the .ppam, rather than the ActivePresentation, with the predictable result that I can't run the macro.
This question implies that it couldn't be done back in 2013 and this link has the same solution.
Is there really no way to run .ppam macro from a context menu?

Try qualifying the reference with the name of your add-in, for example  .OnAction = "'MyAddInName.ppam'!modRibbonInterface.cllbckInsertSlides"

@Domenic Unfortunately that doesn't work, it gives a 'macro cannot be found' error.

Actually, your VBA callback expects an argument.  Therefore, try amending the code so that the parameter is optional, for example Sub cllbckInsertSlides(Optional control As IRibbonControl)

@Domenic Sorry for taking so long to reply. Your suggestion didn't work (caused an issue with the ribbon callback), but in a similar vein I just created a separate callback macro specifically for the context menu. Everything's working now. If you want to post an answer I'm happy to accept it :)

That's great, I'm glad you were able to find a solution.  And thanks for the feedback, cheers!
